# How to predict a size of a process' core file before generating it with GDB?

Tags: linux, debugging, memory, gdb, core-file

How can the size of the core file be predicted based on for example `/proc/pid/maps`, `/proc/pid/coredump_filter`, values shown by `top` like `VIRT RES` and so on?

Generally speaking, on what does the size of the core file depend and what exactly does the file contain (which parts of virtual address space?)?

*I'm a little confused by a fact that the core file may be smaller than a `VIRT` or a sum of all memory ranges in `/proc/pid/maps`, so I suspect the file to be incomplete.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can the size of the core file be predicted based on for example /proc/pid/maps, /proc/pid/coredump_filter, values shown by top like VIRT RES and so on?

The upper bound is the sum of all mappings in `/proc/$$/maps`. However, *usually* read-only mappings are not saved in the `core` (under assumption that you will have the files that are mapped read-only available at the time when you use the `core`).

The lower bound is the sum of all writable mappings in `/proc/$$/maps`. It's a lower bound because the kernel usually also dumps the first page of executable read-only mappings, as that's where linker `BUILD_ID` ELF note is. That note allows GDB to find correct version of the executable or shared libraries used, even if the system has been updated with newer ones. `core` also contains a dump of registers for each thread. There is also some overhead to the ELF format itself.

VIRT and RES are usually not a good estimate: VIRT is "too big" -- it contains read-only mappings, as well as pages that are `mmap`ed into the process, but haven't actually been paged in. RES may be too small if parts of your memory have been swapped out.

> I'm a little confused by a fact that the core file may be smaller than a VIRT or a sum of all memory ranges in /proc/pid/maps, so I suspect the file to be incomplete.

As I explained above, the `core` being smaller than `VIRT` and the sum of all memory ranges in `/proc/pid/maps` is normal and expected.

Finally, if you really wish to find a fairly precise estimate before actually dumping the core, you may wish to study Google [user-space coredumper](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-coredumper/).